# Websocket & HTTP proxy with server between two firewalls

Tags: firewall, proxy, socket

I have a server ("A") running behind a firewall, which serves HTTP and websockets. I have no control over the firewall, but do have an external server ("B") to which the internal server can connect (note that the reverse connection from B to A is not possible due to the firewall). How can I set up some sort of proxy on B such that an Internet client ("C") can access the resources on A?

I'd prefer something lightweight—even a Python program or an SSH tunnel (which I've tried without success)—rather than something more heavyweight but robust.

Comment: Was your question answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it using a nginx webproxy with an ssh tunnel. Assuming my service on A is running on port 3000, from A, I did:

```
ssh -R 3000:localhost:3000 me@B
```

to set up a reverse connection from port 3000 on B to port 3000 on A.

I then set up a nginx proxy to forward both websocket and regular traffic to the ssh port, with the following configuration:

```
events {
  worker_connections 100;  #I'm not expecting many connections
}

http {
  server {
      listen 3001;

      # host name to respond to
      #server_name ws.example.com;

      location / {
          # switch off logging
          access_log off;

          # redirect all HTTP traffic to localhost:3000
          proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
          proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header Host $host;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

          # WebSocket support (nginx 1.4)
          proxy_http_version 1.1;
          proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
          proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
      }
  }
}
```

Now, I can connect with C to `http://B:3001` and everything is transparently forwarded to `http://A:3000`.

The only remaining problem is that the initial connection is a little bit slow, but it may be due to the ssh connection. I'm going to experiment with adding gzip compression to the nginx proxy.

Comment: I anticipated your frustration with the ssh tunnel and put forward openvpn as a reliable and hassle free solution in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems.  First, you have a firewall to circumvent.  Second, you have to reverse proxy websockets.

The first problem is easier. I would start with installing openvpn-server on B and get A connected to it.  You can choose any port the firewall will allow. I have found it to be excellent at maintaining a remote connection and you get encryption to boot.

The second problem is reverse proxying http and websockets.  Websockets is complicated but once openvpn is installed you can use any of the conventional methods to do so without worrying about the firewall. I would attempt to use the websocket proxy features of more recent versions of nginx: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/websocket.html